# using ck4.10, and unable to use audio tags

Tags: ckeditor

When I use the html audio tag, ckeditor just deletes the tag.  I tried using html audio plugin , but it does not work with 4.10. Any way to include audio tag? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of [Advanced Content Filter (ACF)](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter.html).

You need to use [extraAllowedContent](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-extraAllowedContent) like this: `config.extraAllowedContent = 'audio[*]{*}(*)';` to allow audio tag that accepts any attribute, style and class.